# How to understand document completed using Dj Native Jwebbrowser?

Tags: java, swing, jwebbrowser, djnativeswing

I didnt find any document completed method on JWebbrowser object.

```
 String git="git(10);"
 webbrowser.executeJavaScript(git);
 String html=webbrowser.getHTMLContent();
```

this html is include previous page html.Bu I want to take new page.
I'm waiting for help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the listener:

```
    webBrowser.addWebBrowserListener(new WebBrowserAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void loadingProgressChanged(WebBrowserEvent e) {
            if (e.getWebBrowser().getLoadingProgress() == 100) {
                ....
            }
        }
    });
```